# Plasma launcher stuck: plasmashell bug

Tags: debian, kde, kde-plasma-5, debian-stretch

I work with Debian 9 (stretch) with KDE (Plasma 5.8.6) and up to now when I opened the application launcher I could search (in the search bar) by typing, anything I wanted. Now there seems to be a problem, since when I type it's stuck after the first letter. Has anyone experienced anything similar? It happened out of the blue, so far it worked perfectly. I noticed running htop that there is a process `plasmashell --shut-up` "eating" some of my RAM, and I did `killall plasmashell` and subsequently `kstart plasmashell`. Then the problem with the launcher went away, but it needs to be done every time I boot the computer. Is there another solution?